# How to dynamically set deployment approvers?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline, manual-testing

1. Can I dynamically set approvers for a deployment environment?
2. Can I check the commits in the build pipeline for owners?

Some changes in a build need to be manually tested. We have some text in the change list's description that marks if the commit should be manually tested in a particular deployment environment. I want to set the post-approvers to the individuals that are responsible for their changes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Can I dynamically set approvers for a deployment environment?

For this issue , you can set approver through the [Definitions - Update](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/release/definitions/update?view=azure-devops-rest-5.1) rest api.

You can add approver in "postDeployApprovals" argument. For example:

```
"postDeployApprovals": {
  "approvals": [
    {
      "rank": 1,
      "isAutomated": true,
      "isNotificationOn": false,
      "approver": {
        "id": "aeb95c63-4fac-4948-84ce-711b0a9dda97",
        "displayName": "xxx",
        "uniqueName": "xxx@outlook.com",
        "url": "https://vssps.dev.azure.com/xxx/_apis/Identities/aeb95c63-4fac-4948-84ce-711b0a9dda97",
        "imageUrl": "https://dev.azure.com/xxx/_api/_common/identityImage?id=aeb95c63-4fac-4948-84ce-711b0a9dda97"
      },
        "id": 0
      }
  ]
},
```

> Can I check the commits in the build pipeline for owners?

You can check commit on the build summary page:

[image]